# Function is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I trying to display recent "oders" from an order table. But even if I have some orders in the table, I get the message "No orders to get". What is wrong with the code?

```
public static List<OrderInfo> GetOrdersByRecent (int count)
{
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand ();
    comm.CommandText = "OrdersGetByRecent";
    DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter ();
    param.ParameterName = "@Count";
    param.Value = count;
    param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    comm.Parameters.Add (param);
    return ConvertDataTableToOrders (GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand (comm));
}

protected void byRecentGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int recordCount = Int32.Parse(recentCountTextBox.Text);
        List<OrderInfo> orders = CommerceLibAccess.GetOrdersByRecent(recordCount);
        grid.DataSource = orders;
        if (orders.Count == 0)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "<br />No orders to get.";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        errorLabel.Text = "<br />Couldn't get the requested orders!";
    }
    finally
    {
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague. Have you tried debugging the code at all?

Comment: -1: You have to debug yourself - this question is likely to be closed unless you provide small sample that show problem (not a call to a random private function).

Comment: `CommerceLibAccess.GetOrdersByRecent(recordCount)` returns no items. That's it. We can't tell you any more than that because we don't know how that function works, or how your database looks. Put a breakpoint on that line and walk through the code yourself.

Comment: The above are all true, but also what is "OrdersGetByRecent" in your `CommandText` property?  Is that supposed to be a stored procedure?  Or are you just omitting the SELECT string.  If you run "OrdersGetByRecent" in any sql system i've ever encountered... you will either get an error (most likely) or return an empty set.  If you are using a stored procedure you need to declare the `comm.CommandType` property.

Comment: It is stored procedure and I can run it in sql query. I tried comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; but the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get zero orders because

```
List<OrderInfo> orders = CommerceLibAccess.GetOrdersByRecent(recordCount);
```

is returning an empty list.

---

It is returning an empty list because:

```
return ConvertDataTableToOrders (GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand (comm));
```

is returning an empty data-table.

You'll have to dig into your data table to figure out why it thinks its empty.
(maybe because it is actually empty??)

Comment: No offence, but this just says what the comments on the OP said. There is not much we can tell him besides "debug it" and "it returns no rows"

Comment: Yes. There was a mistake in the sql JOIN query.

Answer (score -1):

Table field "OrderID" and the OrderInfo attribute for OrderID needs to be same

```
class OrderInfo
{

int OrderID;

}
```

Check this...

Comment: I am confused what you mean. Where is this attribute? What does this accomplish?

Comment: ok you have a class OrderInfo.Tell me the data members it contains